# ASP.NET Core 6 Web App - Index navigating to .html

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web App with Razor Pages ***(not using MVC)***.
In my `_Layout.cshtml` file I have the following navigation links

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-white" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-white" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-white" asp-page="/Files/Index">Files</a>
</li>
```

The links navigate to the following URLs:

- https://localhost:7223/index.html
- https://localhost:7223/Privacy
- https://localhost:7223/Files

**Why does the "Index" link navigate to `/index.html` instead of `/Index` like the other links?** This is a problem because index.html doesn't exist..

I had been using my app for a while and it used to navigate to `/Index` but after I installed Swashbuckle.AspNetCore it started navigating to `/index.html`

Also note that this is also affecting my `launchUrl` inside my launchSettings.json file.

```
"profiles": {
    "FileService": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7223;http://localhost:5223",
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost:7223/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
```

The above launchUrl launches with https://localhost:7223/index.html but if I explicitly state
`"launchUrl": "https://localhost:7223/Index"` then it works on startup, but the navigation link from the `_Layout` still adds the unwanted `.html` extension.

Thanks

Comment: I think it is because of browser caching. Try opening developer tools, right-click on the refresh button, and choose the last option - Empty Cache and Hard Reload.

Comment: Did you able to resolve the issue? Feel free to share if you have any further concerns on this.

Comment: Yes, clearing the cache like @Anuraj mentioned worked.

Comment: Glad to know that you have successfully resolved that. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you have not set it up as it needs to.
Have you red the info on how to configure it?
Here's the link:
[getting-started-with-swashbuckle_aspnetcore-6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Yes I have already read this documentation but I don't think it's related since the very act of downloading the nuget package is what started the problem. And it persisted after uninstalling the nuget package